# How to show limit of this Composite realation

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\lim _{x\to a}f\left(x\right)\:=\:L \lim _{x\to b}g\left(x\right)=a$ and that f is continuous at a. Then show
that $\lim _{x\to b}\left(f\:\circ \:g\right)\left(x\right)=L$

Comment: Continuity of $f$ at $a$ is not needed. What is needed is the extra assumption that $g(x) \neq a$ as $x \to b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous at $a$, then $f(a)=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L$.

Also, $\lim_{x\to b} f\circ g\; (x)= \lim_{x\to b} f(g(x))= f(\lim_{x\to b} g(x))= f(a)$.
Here I'm using the fact that with continuous functions, we can exchange the limit and the function $f$.

So $\lim _{x\to b}\left(f\:\circ \:g\right)\left(x\right)=L$

Answer (score 1):

For any $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta_{1}>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta_{1}\rightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for any $x$ such that $|x-a|<\delta_{1}$. Moreover, there exist $\delta_{2}>0$ such that $|g(x)-a|<\delta_{1}$ for any $x$ that satisfy $|x-b|<\delta_{2}$. Therefore, $|x-b|<\delta_{2}$ implies $|f(g(x))-L|<\epsilon$ for any $x$ that satisfies $|x-b|<\delta_{2}$.